# JS includes for an array of objects contains an object always return false

Tags: javascript

I'm using `includes` to check if an array of objects contains an object, but it always return false

```js
const record = {
  id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  number:1,
  priority:0
}

const selectedRows = [{
 id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
 key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
 number:1,
 priority:0
}]

alert(selectedRows.includes(record));
```

I don't understand why it works this way. How to make the check work properly?

Comment: You need to write a method to compare objects by property, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

That's because objects are only equal to themselves, and only themselves.*

```
console.log({x: 1} === {x: 1}); // outputs false
```

whereas

```
const obj = {x: 1}
console.log(obj === obj); // outputs true.
```

---

The array doesn't actually includes `record`, only an object that looks like it.

<sup>* Barring oddities like `.valueOf()` and `.toString()` etc.</sup>

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#A_model_for_understanding_equality_comparisons

Comment: I really did not want to conflate OP with the differences, it's all the same for objects, anyway. (If they were asking about NaN, it would have been a different answer)

Comment: I see. I just provided that link since the `.includes` documentation uses the seem evaluation and it is explicit there. :)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work cause u create two different objects, they are not the same.

It will return true in this case

```
const record = {
  id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  number:1,
  priority:0
}

const selectedRows = [record]

alert(selectedRows.includes(record));
```

For check equallity of two objects, u can read answer to this question [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)
So, in your case, u should iterate through array and try to compare your object with elements

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Javascript are reference types. Meaning when they are compared, instead of comparing their properties one-by-one, the engine simply checks whether they point to same memory address.

In your case `record` object is not part of the array because during array initialization you create a separate object using the object initialization syntax `{...}`. Instead if you create the array using `[records]` you get the expected result:

```js
const record = {
  id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  number:1,
  priority:0
}

const selectedRows = [record];

// Result: true
alert(selectedRows.includes(record));
```

---

Another quick way to check this would be to modify `record` object and then compare it with the object in the array. You will notice that they are different, and that's because those two are two different objects:

```js
const record = {
  id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  number:1,
  priority:0
}

const selectedRows = [{
 id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
 key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
 number:1,
 priority:0
}];

console.log("Modifying properties in record:");
record.id = "0";
record.key = "0";
console.log("Record: ", record);
console.log("Array content: ", selectedRows);
```

Comment: I see. So how to make the check?

Comment: @Heidel The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/5894241) explains how you could compare such objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method which  tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test.

This snippet is testing only id but multiple fields can also be included

```js
const record = {
  id: "6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  key: "6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  number: 1,
  priority: 0
}

const selectedRows = [{
  id: "6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  key: "6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  number: 1,
  priority: 0
}]

let x = selectedRows.some((item) => {
  return record.id === item.id
})
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const record = {
  id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  number:1,
  priority:0
}

const selectedRows = [{
 id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
 key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
 number:1,
 priority:0
}]

//will alert the position of the element
//if -1 then element is not found
alert(selectedRows.findIndex(record => record.id === '6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457'));
```

**You should check on id of element**

Answer (score 1):

`includes` won't work for two different `object`. You can do something like this using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) perhaps:

```js
const record = {
  id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
  number:1,
  priority:0
}

const selectedRows = [{
 id:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
 key:"6c86e6c7-590a-44af-8492-1b83be1bf457",
 number:1,
 priority:0
}]

console.log(selectedRows.some(obj => JSON.stringify(obj) == JSON.stringify(record)));
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the `object` index in the array.